# Copy .text section and add as new section at the end breaks executable

Tags: assembly, portable-executable

I have an existing PE binary which I am manually patching. I am copying the `.text` section (which is at the beginning) and add it at the end of the section table. Then I overwrite the first/old `.text` section with all `0xCC`. Because of this change, the virtual address of the instructions itself are of course changed. Since I have instructions like `mov eax, dword ptr [rip + 0x2024]` (it will point to an address in the `.data` section) in the added/moved `.text` section, it will point to the wrong stuff (since `rip` is different because the whole instruction is at a new RVA it will not point to that location in the `.data` section anymore).

Would I need to manually patch the actual machine code as well, so that it points to the correct offset in the `.data` section again? Or are there better/smarter ways to fix my PE image so the existing machine code works in the new/moved section?

The reason I want to move it to a new section at the end is because I am mutating the original code (adding dead code, nops etc.). Since this would cause the size of the code to change, it seemed better to move the entire mutated code (can be 2-3x bigger than the original) in a new section. Right now I am disassembling the original code and fixup all `call`, `jmp` and `jcc` instructions to use the correct RVA's. Am I doing more work than necessary here?

Could it maybe be possible to use relocations to achieve what I want in an easier way?

Comment: In general you can't move one section relative to another section because the two sections may refer to an object in the other section using relative addressing that assumes the relative distance between the two sections never changes.  Note that `[eip + 0x2024]` isn't a valid addressing mode, you might mean `[rip + 0x2024]` which can appear in 64-bit code.

Comment: @RossRidge I see. So the only way would be to disassemble the code in the section and fix up every instruction using a relative address outside itself?

Comment: If you want add more code to the executable you should create a new section at the end of executable and put the code there.

Comment: @RossRidge Well the thing is I am mutating the original code (adding dead code inbetween, nops etc.). So that's why I am moving it to a new section so it can grow more easily. Basically I am taking code in the original text section, then change it around a bit and then put it back at the end of the section table.

I already fixed all call, jmp and jcc instructions used inside the code, which seems to work fine. But I was wondering if there is a better way than manually disassembling, fixing jumps etc. and then assembling it again.

Comment: I'd put a JMP instruction at the start of the function in the .text section that jumps to your mutated code in the new section. Also don't overwrite the entire .text section since there can be data in there, only overwrite the functions you've mutated.